# Redux-toolkit, как обновить slice внутри другого slice

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

Имеется хранилище с вызовом модального окна с информацией об ошибки. Туда нужно передать информацию (title, true (открыть окно) и сообщение об ошибки). В другом slice, при получении клиентов через createAsyncThunk и использовании extraReducers, я обрабатываю ошибку, которая пришла с сервера.

```
builder.addCase(getClientsList.rejected, (state, action) => {
  const modal: any = {
    title: "Ошибка",
    children: <Error error={action.error.message} />,
    open: true
  };
  Modal(modal);
});
```

В моем случае функция modal используется для dispatch и вызова метода изменения состояния слайса модального окна.
Пытался прямиком в AddCase запихать диспатч - появляется ошибка, что диспатч должен быть внутри компонента.
Хорошо, сделаю компонен Model, но и тут возникает ошибка: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons

Так же пробовал сделать это таком образом: modalActions.openModalError(modal)
Но так же безуспешно. Как правильно обновлять slice внутри другого slice ?
Я особо в фронте не шарю, больше по бэку. Спасибо!